# regex replace space between words in string

Tags: regex, postgresql

Say we have the strings on the left and we want to replace empty space between words with `<->`

`" Power Lines"` => `" Power<->Lines"`

Even further, can regex also remove spaces such as a trim in the same regex?

`" Power Lines"` => `"Power<->Lines"`

These questions pertain to postgres regex_replace function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easier than a regex you can do:

```
SELECT replace(trim(both ' ' from ' Power Lines'), ' ', '<->');
+---------------+
| replace       |
|---------------|
| Power<->Lines |
+---------------+
SELECT 1
Time: 0.003s
```

If you want to do it with a Regex, the syntax is `regexp_replace(string text, pattern text, replacement text [, flags text])` (see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html)